# How to locking database record for IsolationLevel RepeatableRead in ABP UnitOfWork?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, unit-of-work

It's better if this issue is explained with an example. I have a database table **`VoucherNumber`** with an **`int`** column named **`[TotalNumberRecord]`**. It has only a record with the initial value of **`TotalNumberRecord`** == 0.

In my **`VoucherNumberAppService.cs`**, there are the following 2 methods

```
        public async void TestIncrementA(string id)
        {
            using var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin(isolationLevel: System.Data.IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead);
            var query = await _voucherNumberService.GetQueryableAsync();
            query = query.Where(p => p.Id == id);
            var sections = await AsyncExecuter.FirstOrDefaultAsync(query);
            sections.TotalNumberRecord++;
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            await _voucherNumberService.UpdateAsync(sections);
            await unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();
        }
```

```
        public async void TestIncrementB(string id)
        {
            using var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin(isolationLevel: System.Data.IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead);
            var query = await _voucherNumberService.GetQueryableAsync();
            query = query.Where(p => p.Id == id);
            var sections = await AsyncExecuter.FirstOrDefaultAsync(query);
            sections.TotalNumberRecord++;
            await _voucherNumberService.UpdateAsync(sections);
            await unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();
        }
```

The 2 methods are essentially the same which increment the value of the column **`TotalNumberRecord`** by one except that the first method delays the thread.

Now I run 2 methods

```
TestIncrementA(id);
TestIncrementB(id);
```

I would expect the value of **`TotalNumberRecord`** in my database to be 2 now since it's been incremented twice. However it's only 1.
Is there something that I'm overlooking?

Comment: ABP doesn't handle this ([aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate#50](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/50)). There's no easy way to SELECT FOR UPDATE / UPDLOCK in EF Core ([dotnet/efcore#26042](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26042)). You can implement `IDbCommandInterceptor` to use [command interception to add query hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors#example-command-interception-to-add-query-hints).

Comment: You can try DbConcurrency in Entity Framework or write manual queries that hold lock while updating entry